# Swift serial DispatchQueue not executing serially

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async, dispatch-queue

Hey in my code the function "sendRequest" is called multiple times which sends a request to a server. The server processes all requests one after the other and sends back a multiple responses. Now I want to process these responses in the function "handleResponse", but in a serial queue. So handleResponse will only be called once at the same time. But now I have the case that my logs look like this:

```
[15.05.2023 11:28:00.711] DEBUG NetworkDataHandler:52 - start handleResponse
[15.05.2023 11:28:00.710] DEBUG NetworkDataHandler:52 - start handleResponse
[15.05.2023 11:28:00.713] DEBUG NetworkDataHandler:52 - start handleResponse
[15.05.2023 11:28:00.713] DEBUG NetworkDataHandler:52 - start handleResponse
[15.05.2023 11:28:00.714] DEBUG NetworkDataHandler:52 - start handleResponse
...
```

handleResponse is thus called several times, although it has not yet been completed. How can I get the callback to work serially?

Simplified code:

```swift
func sendRequest() { // is called several times
    applicationNetworkManager().sendQuery(
        ...
        successHandler: { response in
 
            let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
                self!.handleResponse(response: response)
            }
            let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue", qos: .background)
            serialQueue.async(execute: workItem)
        }
    )
}

func handleResponse(response: Response) {
    Logger.d("start handleResponse")

    // do some stuff and write response data to local storage

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // update ui
    }

    Logger.d("end handleResponse")
}
```

Comment: Each time you call `sendRequest` you are creating a new serial dispatch queue. You need to create the queue once and dispatch work to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sendRequest` you are creating a new dispatch queue each time you call `let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue", qos: .background)`. Even though all of the queue instances have the same label, they are different queues.

You don't show how you create the class that contains `sendRequest`, so I am not sure if there is one instance of this class or if you have multiple instances.

It is also best to avoid the `.background` QoS; This QoS level can be starved for CPU in a low power situation.  `.utility` is a good choice.

Assuming you have one instance you would use something like:

```
class NetworkHandler {

    let myQueue: DispatchQueue

    init() {
        self.myQueue = DispatchQueue(label:"serialQueue", qos: .utility)
    }
}
```

You can then use this queue in your handler.

Comment: Thank you that worked. But with "target: DISPATCH_TARGET_QUEUE_DEFAULT" it shows the error Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'DispatchQueue?'. Maybe its easy to solve, but i will look at it later :)

Comment: The documentation suggests the use of that constant, but it doesn't seem to work and it isn't documented anywhere else, so I changed it to use a global queue

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the advice to manually specify the target the global queue. Let `libDispatch` do this for you. FWIW, it is probably best to omit that target parameter altogether, which will use the default value of `nil`. FWIW, that Objective-C constant, `DISPATCH_TARGET_QUEUE_DEFAULT` [is defined as `NULL`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/7fb9d5ceea562d60fe34ec55b6b165ae5aca38eb/dispatch/queue.h#L870), too. And IIRC, it uses the worker thread pool, anyway.

Comment: @Rob, yes, after I wrote my last comment, I dug into the definition of that value and it is defined as NULL, but you get an error if you specify it as the argument in Swift (despite Apple's documentation saying you should), but you can specify `nil`, which is, as you say, the default.

Comment: Interestingly, in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) it states that you should target your serial dispatch queue to a global queue to avoid excess thread creation, but if that is the default behaviour when you create a queue, why do they say this explicitly?

Comment: Two observations: First, I cannot say definitively, but I distinctly remember testing private queues in years gone by and experienced different behavior. But it doesn't matter as the contemporary behavior is what it is. Second, their advice is within the context of “creating too many private concurrent dispatch queues.” So, sure, if creating lots of private queues (which is, itself, code smell, IMHO), then specify target (and realize that you are now subject to the very limited worker thread-pool size of that global queue across all your queues). I'd still generally not specify a target.